# How to start the Xdebug server on PHPDesigner 8

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug, phpdesigner

I'm using XAMPP to run a PHP application in Windows 8, using PHP v5.5.6

I've downloaded the `php_xdebug*.dll` and placed it in `C:\xampp\php\ext\`

I've configured the `[XDebug]` section in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` like this:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.7-5.5-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\ProgramData\phpDesigner\XDebugCache"
```

I've also configured the Prefferences->Debugger to use the `C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe` and the `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

But still I can not debug my code. When I click on the "Debug" button, nothing happens. If i go to Debug->Xdebug Server->Start, nothing happens.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Daniel, did you ever get it to work? If so, could you please post (and accept) an answer? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I gave up. I used Webstorm with plugins.

Comment: JetBrains do make the best IDEs, but they are too expensive for me :-(  Why WebStorm, and not PhpStorm? Also, you still have to configure your PHP.ini, no matter which IDE you use. And, please note,t hat they recently released Xdebug v 3, which needs different entries in PHP.ini When I did that, I had no problems launching a URL, with parameters, from PhpDesigner & hitting a breakpoints. What I cannot do yet is is to have the IDE detect when my browser based app sends an AJAX request :-(

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have installed correctly
you should go to 
`Run -> Click Start listening for PHP connections` ( or something like that ).

Now phpstorm is listening for connection. Go back to you browser and hit refresh. If everything was configured as it should ( btw have a look in preferences in phpstorm for xdebug, port and all others ) phpstorm should be able to catch the connection and give you the opportunity to step into lines ( F7, F8 )

Comment: I'm not using PHPStorm, I'm using PHPDesigner. There is no Run -> Click Start listening for PHP connections

Comment: oh it seams that I failed :) I used phpdesigner and I can tell you that worth changing to phpstorm. I can't remember though how its working in phpDesigner, but should be the same, anyway if you hit debug from the IDE debug will start on the file you are, which is not always good.

Comment: Also there is  `xdebug.remote_autostart` which default to 0, from what I remember you need to have either a get, post or a cookie variable set so that xdebug to start debugging or change to 1. There is a Chrome extension for that. Do a search for them.

Comment: If i hit debug, nothing happens. PHPStorm is not free and I don't want to spend more money in another IDE.